# How to remove all of certain data types from list?

Tags: python, string, list

I am having some trouble removing only strings from a list of strings and integers. This may seem silly, yet it's true:

```
>>> A = [1, '2', '3', 4, '5', '4', 6, 56, 7, '4', 6, '543']
>>> 
>>> for i in A:
        if type(i) is str:
                    A.remove(i)


>>> A
[1, '3', 4, 6, 56, 7, '4', 6]
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to what is happening, or if I am simply doing something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python/1207500#1207500

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use built-in `filter` function:

```
filtered_A = filter(lambda i:not(type(i) is str), A)
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing elements while loop over the list does not work.

Use list comprehension instead:

```
>>> A = [1, '2', '3', 4, '5', '4', 6, 56, 7, '4', 6, '543']
>>> [x for x in A if not isinstance(x, str)]
[1, 4, 6, 56, 7, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any particular reason why a loop does not work this way?

Comment: If using Python 2.x, then `basestring` may be more suitable here - unless `unicode` is to be included...

Comment: @Plopperzz, If you remove an element, index used interally get out of sync.

Comment: @Plopperzz There is. Iterating over elements in a collection assumes that this collection does not change during iteration. If you change the collection (which you do), this will result in some kind of undefined behaviour

Comment: @Plopperzz If you want to use iteration, you should iterate over a copy (for a list it is simply `A[:]`), but in this case it is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Never alter(especially add or remove elements) the container you're looping on, because iterators on that container are not going to be informed of your alterations and, as you've noticed, that's quite likely to produce a very different loop and/or an incorrect one.

Like in this case, the first element to be removed from the list is `'2'`. In the next iteration, the loop will work for `A[2]`, which is now `4`. Hence, the loop never ran for element `'3'`.

List comprehensions are best choice for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: A = [1, '2', '3', 4, '5', '4', 6, 56, 7, '4', 6, '543']

In [2]: [x for x in A if type(x)!=str]
Out[2]: [1, 4, 6, 56, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove elements from the list you are looping over, since you won't catch every element:

```
A = [1, '2', '3', 4, '5', '4', 6, 56, 7, '4', 6, '543']

for i in A:
    print(repr(i))
    if type(i) is str:
        A.remove(i)

# 1, '2', 4, '5', 6, 56, 7, '4', '543'
```

If you need an explicit loop, copy the list (see the [section about for-loop in the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)):

```
for x in A[:]:
    if isinstance(x, str):
         A.remove(x)
```

In this case you should use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), though.

```
[x for x in A if isinstance(x, int)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to keep only number-like objects in your list, then that can be made more explicit by using:

```
A = [1, '2', '3', 4, '5', '4', 6, 56, 7, '4', 6, '543']

from numbers import Number
A[:] = [el for el in A if isinstance(el, Number)]
# [1, 4, 6, 56, 7, 6]
```

Then, if you wanted to narrow down on specific types of numbers (eg, just ints), you could do:

```
A = [1, 1.0, 1j]

from numbers import Integral
A[:] = [el for el in A if isinstance(el, Integral)]
# [1]
```